# Editing the java code for lexicograhical order of user input no. of words

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to code a program that asks the user to input `n` words one on each line and gives the output as lexicographical sorted words.

It asks the user to input the number of words on 1st line and then the words one on each line. I am supposed to use a multi-dimensional array for this program.

My code works fine except that it is unable to take `n` number of words as input by the user but instead takes only `n - 1` words.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = input.nextInt();
  String arr[] = new String[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = input.nextLine();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[j])>0) {
        String temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please post the error you get back, and what you have tried to fix it.  Cheers

Comment: `nextLine()` automatically moves down after returning the user input.

Comment: @Niraj thank you so much pointing out the `nextLine()` which was the source of error in my program. Replacing it with the `next()` solved the problem. I was then able to input the desired 'n' number of words as the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering has to do with the Scanner's `nextInt()` method. It will **only** read a integer from the input buffer and will leave the newline character at the end of the first line in the buffer.

This means, that your first call to `nextLine()` after that will read an empty string and consume the newline character.

An easy fix for that is to just put a `input.nextLine()` call somewhere between `input.nextInt()` and your read-loop.

Comment: I am sorry. I wasn't able to understand the source of my error at first but after re-reading your post and implementing it in my program, I now understand it was the `nextInt()` that was creating an empty string.and by inserting a `nextLine()`immediately after nextInt() and before the read-loop, solved the empty string problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ask the user to enter the words and let the program decide the number of words.

```
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter words:");
          String data = input.nextLine();
          String[] arr= data.split("\\s+"); //splits the word by space and stores the words in pieces 
 // and then do the lexicographical operations here
```